# Android: problem with endless adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm trying to use "http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless" to implement pagination for my list views.

I'm getting the first page results correctly, when I scrolled down to the bottom of the 1st page, i'm seeing the spinning wheel but im not getting any results.

I noticed from the LogCat that, getPendingView(), cacheInBackground(), appendCachedData() and MyCustomAdapter's getView() are getting called infinately.

Can anybody plz help.

Thanks,
nehatha.

Here is my code snippet:

```
Activity{
    onCreate() {
        myList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        setListAdapter(new DemoAdapter(myList));
        nextLink = "service_url"; //for first page results (say 1-25)
    }

    final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
            //
            updateList(jsonResponse);
        }
    };

    updateList(String jsonString) {
        //parse json
        //add to `myList`
        //update `nextLink`, if there is next page available
    }

    class DemoAdapter extends EndlessAdapter {
        private RotateAnimation rotate=null;

        DemoAdapter(List<Item> list) {          
            super(new MyCustomAdapter(LatestUpdatesList.this, R.layout.latest_update_item, list));
            //rotate code
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean cacheInBackground() {
            if(nextLink != null && nextLink.length() > 0){
                HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler(nextLink, "GET", handler);
                Thread latestUpdatesThread = new Thread(httpHandler);
                latestUpdatesThread.start();
                return true;
            }
            return false;           
        }

        @Override
        protected void appendCachedData() {
            MyCustomAdapter adapter = (MyCustomAdapter)getWrappedAdapter();
            adapter.setList(myList);

        }
    } //DemoAdapter

} //Activitiy
```

Comment: Can you please help me on this EndlessAdapter as your code seems similar to my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by not calling my web service in a new thread (inside  cacheInBackground() method). Instead i'm directly calling my HttpHandler's get() method directly. But I'm not sure this is the best fix.

Thanks,
nehatha

Comment: Can you please help me on this EndlessAdapter as your code seems similar to my requirement?